# In django how to customize model admin to save in auth_user and another unrelated model simultaneously?

Tags: python, django

In django 3.0, I have 3 model classes derieved from an abstract model class as:

```
class AbstractPerson(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    muser_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (not self.pk) and (self.email):
            muser = User.objects.get(id=self.muser_id).count()
            if muser:
                u = User()
                u.username = self.first_name.lower()
                u.is_staff = True
                u.first_name = self.first_name
                u.last_name = self.last_name
                u.email = self.email
                u.save()

        return super(AbstractPerson, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

One of the model class: Customer class has been derieved from this abstract class. What I have tried by overriding the save method of the abstract class model to save the instance in django auth user and customer model. The CustomerModelForm is defined as follows This works fine during 'Add customer'.

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Email already exists"),
                                        code='invalid')

        return email
```

But during edit Customer, it is possible that the email id of the customer along with all other attributes might also change. How to then access the corresponding auth User details for the same customer? I require to store the User 'id' value in 'muser_id' attribute of the customer instance.  I have used instance_post_save method for the same as follows:

```
def instance_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        #print(type(instance),'iiiii')
        try:
            u = User()
            u.username = instance.first_name
            u.is_staff = True
            u.first_name = instance.first_name
            u.last_name = instance.last_name
            u.email = instance.email
            u.save(commit=True)
            u = User.objects.get(email=instance.email)
            instance.update({muser_id: u.id})
            instance.save()
            print(instance,'tttttttttttttttt')
        except Exception as e:
            log.info(e)        
    u = User.objects.get(id=instance.muser_id)
    u.username = instance.first_name
    u.is_staff = True
    u.first_name = instance.first_name
    u.last_name = instance.last_name
    u.email = instance.email
    u.save()

    return
```

This is not allowing me to persist the User id in the customer model instance, so that it can be accessed during **Edit customer**. How do I accomplish this? Note: The email id is unique across all the models defined in the app including the customer, User etc.

Comment: You might want to read about [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists) and [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved finally: AbstractPerson class save method changes:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if (not self.pk) and (self.email):
         muser = User.objects.filter(email=self.email).count()  # changed
```

The instance_post_save method changes:

```
def instance_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        muser = User.objects.get(email=instance.email)
        instance.muser_id=muser.id
        instance.save()
    else:
        u = User.objects.get(id=instance.muser_id)
        u.username = instance.first_name
        u.is_staff = True
        u.first_name = instance.first_name
        u.last_name = instance.last_name
        u.email = instance.email
        u.save()

    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AbstractPerson(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    some attributes

class OtherPerson(AbstractPerson):
    #... attrs ...
```

Then implement the user registration and configuration of the extended models of the User model, to change fields of some model, for example a child class of AbstractPerson can use a generic view like UpdateView and specify the fields.
So both models would be related to a one-to-one relationship and not by an id that you would have to use constantly to filter and get users.

Comment: I don't want a foreign key ref. in the models to User.

Comment: @user956424 Another way to do it without using FK is to inherit AbstractPerson from AbstractUser and use its default attributes, then creating instances of type AbstractPerson would behave the same way. I say this from my point of view, because what I see is that you want to extend the user model.

Comment: I don't want to inherit AbstractUser as I have users in different groups who can access diff. parts of the model admin when they login

Comment: @user956424 Ok, sorry, i am not very clear what you want to do. Good luck.

Comment: No problem Leandro, atleast you have given some good suggestions